# Alamofire photo upload with key of the file in body

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am able to upload a photo via Postman but in my iOS application it fails, and it is so weird that I still get a `.success` from `encodingCompletion`.

Here is part of my code

> UpdateUserInfo

```
    //
    // Update user info
    //
    func updateUserInfo(){
        var imageData: Data!
        var url = ""
        if let userId = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: USER_ID_KEY){
            url = URL_USER_UPLOAD_PIC + userId
        }
        if pickedImage != nil{
            imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
            //imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage!, 1.0)
        }
        let token = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: USER_LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY)!


        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
        ]

        if imageData != nil{
            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "fileset", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }, to: url,
               method: .post,
               headers: headers,
               encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    print("Donkey Success \(String(describing: upload.response?.statusCode))")
                    upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    })
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                    print("Donkey Fail")
                }
            })
        }


    }
```

and in my postman I have

> Postman

[image]

My first question is why I am getting a .success if it fails to upload?

and my second question is, do I need to put the key "pic" (seen in Postman) somewhere in my request? if so where?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Post man Image  Key is `pic` but in your code its `"fileset"`

change to

```
        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "pic", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
```

> And `success` is  Result of encoding not uploading processs
>
> > EncodingResult  is MultipartFormDataEncodingResult that Defines
> >     whether the `MultipartFormData` encoding was successful and contains
> >     result of the encoding as associated values.  **- Success**: Represents a successful `MultipartFormData` encoding and contains the
> >     new `UploadRequest` along with
> >                   streaming information.    **- Failure**: Used to represent a failure in the `MultipartFormData` encoding and also
> >     contains the encoding

Comment: Ahhh Thank you, that was it the whole time. could you please give me a hint how I can check if the photo upload was successful? I tried to type `.responseJSON` after the last `})` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check status code of response I’m out now when back I will post to you

Comment: I can't get the response, that's the problem. ok I will wait.